# Xamarin Forms com Azure

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-forms, xamarin.portable

Estou criando um aplicativo com integração com o Azure, quanto tento instanciar o `MobileServiceClient` tenho a seguinte exeção

> Method 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression'
>   not found.

Aqui está a definição da minha classe

```
public class AzureClient
{
    private IMobileServiceClient _client;
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<Contact> _table;
    private const string serviceUri = "http://{app}.azurewebsites.net/";
    const string dbPath = "contactDb";

    public AzureClient()
    {
        _client = new MobileServiceClient(serviceUri);

        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(dbPath);
        store.DefineTable<Contact>();
        _client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

        _table = _client.GetSyncTable<Contact>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Contact>> GetContacts()
    {
        var empty = new Contact[0];
        try
        {
            if (Plugin.Connectivity.CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                await SyncAsync();
            return await _table.ToEnumerableAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return empty;
        }
    }

    public async void AddContact(Contact contact)
    {
        await _table.InsertAsync(contact);
    }

    public async Task SyncAsync()
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<MobileServiceTableOperationError> syncErrors = null;

        try
        {
            await _client.SyncContext.PushAsync();

            await _table.PullAsync("allContacts", _table.CreateQuery());
        }
        catch (MobileServicePushFailedException pushEx)
        {
            if (pushEx.PushResult != null)
                syncErrors = pushEx.PushResult.Errors;
        }
    }

    public async Task CleanData ()
    {
        await _table.PurgeAsync("allContacts", _table.CreateQuery(), new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
    }
}
```

O erro acontece quando tento executar o projeto para Android.
O código fonte completo do projeto encontra-se na minha conta do [github](https://github.com/pablotdv/MaratonaXamarin/tree/master/Modulo05/Licao04)

Comment: Eu ia fazer essa maratona, mas não estou em condições no momento. Estou querendo aprender o Xamarin também.

Comment: Pois olha, está sendo uma maratona mesmo. Mas está sendo bem proveitosa o bom que vou ter feriadão de carnaval e vai dar pra pesquisar mais sobre esses problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

também estou fazendo a Maratona.

Você adicionou a referência do HTTP client nos seus projetos (incluindo a PCL) ?

Se não, tente adicionar e veja se o problema continua.

Comment: Pois olha, acredito que faltava dar um clean e um build no projeto, ou até mesmo fechar e abrir o VS, pois eu sai e voltei para casa e funcionou.

Comment: ..rs.. as vezes acontece.